# c++ getting a reference to a pix array from an image

Tags: c++, bmp

```
   void drawImage(HWND &hWnd,HBITMAP &hBitmap)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
        HDC             hdc;
        BITMAP          bitmap;
        HDC             hdcMem;
        HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;

        RECT rec;
        ::GetClientRect(hWnd,&rec);

        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);

        int* x = (int*)bitmap.bmBits; ?? problem
        x[0] = 0xff00ff;


//draw image so it fits entire window
        StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rec.right, rec.bottom, hdcMem, 0, 0,bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);


        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
```

In the above code i have a simple window and im drawing a BMP image onto the it. The problem is i dont know how to get a reference to the internal int array. i want to be able to change and manipulate the pixels in the image at will.

i tryed:

```
int* x = (int*)bitmap.bmBits;
x[0] = 0xff00ff;
```

but the screen is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GetBitmapBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or better, [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

BTW, you don't habe to pass `HWND`s and `HBITMAP`s by reference, unless you want to change their values, which I don't think it's the case. They are numerical values (pointers actually) so you don't gain anything.

Comment: thanks alot! right HWND is an int so passing by reference is just coping the address which is also an int.

Comment: `HWND` is not an integer, but a pointer; don't cast `HWND`s to `int`, or you will have problems on 64-bit platforms.